# i was writing test cases for actions but having received anonymous function while using dispach using jest and enzyme

Tags: reactjs, unit-testing, redux, jestjs, enzyme

I was receiving:

```
  Expected: {"data": true, "type": "USER"}
    Received: [Function anonymous]
```

```
export function userDispatch(data) {
  return dispatch => {
    //update the screens
    dispatch(user(data));
  }
}

export function user(data) {
  return {
    type: USER,
    data
  }
}
```

```
  it("testing userDispatch", () => {
      const data = true
      const expectedAction = {
        type: USER,
        data
      }
    expect(actions.userDispatch(data)).toEqual(expectedAction)
    })
```

Comment: `userDispatch` returns a function that takes `dispatch` and calls it with the action, **not** the action.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing a `thunk` action creator named `userDispatch` here.
Also, you have a *normal action creator* called `user` here.

A `thunk` is a function that needs to be dispatched to do anything - so in the current state, calling

```
dispatch(userDispatch(data))
```

does exactly the same as calling

```
dispatch(user(data))
```

`userDispatch` is just completely useless and you can replace it with `user` everywhere you use it - including your test.

If it makes sense to test an action creator at all is highly debatable. The Redux documentation does not really encourage such things:

(from https://redux.js.org/usage/writing-tests)

> The return value of action creators is considered an implementation detail within your application, and when following an integration testing style, do not need explicit tests.

Please be aware, that generally this is a very outdated style of Redux and modern Redux will auto-generate action creators for you. Also, in modern Redux you will not write `switch case` reducers or use `connect`. You might have been following outdated (and in case of this thunk action creator, simply misguided) tutorials.

Best follow the official Redux tutorial at https://redux.js.org/tutorials/essentials/part-1-overview-concepts